# rsync gets stuck on *.png files

Tags: cron, rsync, xubuntu, png

I have been running the following `rsync` command as a cronjob for the past month. Today I discovered that this has been getting stuck on a `*.png` file and none of my other data has been backing up! In the meantime I've excluded `*.png` files and rsync has been working again, but I'd like a comprehensive solution to back up ALL of my files if possible.

This is getting stuck on `*.png` files

```
rsync -rcvl --delete --progress /home/user/target /media/user/backup/source
```

This is my temporary fix

```
rsync -rcvl --delete --progress --exclude='*.png' /home/user/target /media/user/backup/source
```

Each image is only ~300k.

The filesystems of both the target and source directories are `fuseblk`. The source dir is a Western Digital 4TB external hard-drive that is connected via USB 3.0.

**EDIT:** 
I was able to pin-down the problem after piping my `rsync` command into a `grep failed`. This revealed several files that had `:` characters in the file name, which `rsync` was unable to process. After renaming each of these files (replacing each `:` with `_`), and removing the `--exclude='*.png'` flag, the above `rsync` command successfully backed up my system!

Comment: How large are the large files and what filesystem type does the destination directory live on?

Comment: Yes it still gets stuck outside of crontab. The png starts to copy, but stalls at about 11% in. I'm still trying working on the strace results.

Comment: I suspect concurrency/botteneck issues writing into USB disks and fuse to boot. I would stop using fuse for starters, and use a filesystem supported by Linux for starters. The ideal situation would be them not being USB. We also do not know either you work limitation, the USB version and whether you are using USB for something else.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am using USB 3.0. I don't think I'll be able to reformat either drive at this point. There is too much data and no where else for me to store it while I change filesystems.

Comment: Is this to an NTFS filesystem?

Comment: I'm running Xubuntu on a 1TB SSD that is using the fuseblk filesystem. Both the source and target directories are using fuseblk unfortunately. I can't afford to switch filesystems at the moment. I had no idea that fuseblk would cause problems in the future. Lesson learned!